# Transpose pandas DF based on value data type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have pandas `DataFrame` A. I am struggling transforming this into my desired format, see `DataFrame` B. I tried `pivot` or `melt` but I am not sure how I could make it conditional (`string` values to `FIELD_STR_VALUE`, `numeric` values to `FIELD_NUM_VALUE`). I was hoping you could point me the right direction.

A: Input DataFrame

```
|FIELD_A |FIELD_B |FIELD_C |FIELD_D |
|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|123123  |8       |a       |23423   |
|123124  |7       |c       |6464    |
|123144  |99      |x       |234     |
```

B: Desired output DataFrame

```
|ID |FIELD_A |FIELD_NAME |FIELD_STR_VALUE |FIELD_NUM_VALUE |
|---|--------|-----------|----------------|----------------|
|1  |123123  |B          |                |8               |
|2  |123123  |C          |a               |                |
|3  |123123  |D          |                |23423           |
|4  |123124  |B          |                |7               |
|5  |123124  |C          |c               |                |
|6  |123124  |D          |                |6464            |
|7  |123144  |B          |                |99              |
|8  |123144  |C          |x               |                |
|9  |123144  |D          |                |234             |
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
# dic = {np.int64: 'NUM', object: 'STR'}

(df.set_index('FIELD_A')
   .pipe(lambda d: d.set_axis(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
          [d.columns, d.dtypes],
         # or for custom NAMES
         #[d.columns, d.dtypes.map(dic)],
                              names=['FIELD_NAME', None]),
                              axis=1)
        )
   .stack(0).add_prefix('FIELD_').add_suffix('_VALUE')
   .reset_index()
)
```

*NB. if you really want STR/NUM, `map` those strings from the dtypes (see comments in code).*

Output:

```
   FIELD_A FIELD_NAME  FIELD_int64_VALUE FIELD_object_VALUE
0   123123    FIELD_B                8.0                NaN
1   123123    FIELD_C                NaN                  a
2   123123    FIELD_D            23423.0                NaN
3   123124    FIELD_B                7.0                NaN
4   123124    FIELD_C                NaN                  c
5   123124    FIELD_D             6464.0                NaN
6   123144    FIELD_B               99.0                NaN
7   123144    FIELD_C                NaN                  x
8   123144    FIELD_D              234.0                NaN
```

Comment: Dang, never even heard of `pipe` function...

Comment: Not strictly necessary here, but enables to use everything in a chain

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm currently looking into why/how this works.

Comment: Let me know if you have questions (I might not answer immediately, might go AFK)

Comment: I added commented code for a variant

Comment: Yup, I came up with this, which I guess is similar. Yours might be more efficient because I'm calling a function: `[ d.columns, [ "numeric" if is_numeric_dtype(x) else "string" for x in d.dtypes ], ]` Thanks again!

Comment: It's easier if you just want to split numeric vs other, mine would require to list the expected types ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can also try this:

```
(df.melt('FIELD_A')
 .pipe(lambda d: d[['FIELD_A', 'value']].join(d.variable.str.extract('\w+_(?P<FIELD_NAME>\w+)')))
 .pipe(lambda g: g[['FIELD_A', 'FIELD_NAME']].join(g.value.astype(str).str.extract('(?P<FIELD_STR_VALUE>\D+)|(?P<FIELD_NUM_VALUE>\d+)')))
 .sort_values('FIELD_A'))

   FIELD_A FIELD_NAME FIELD_STR_VALUE FIELD_NUM_VALUE
0   123123          B             NaN               8
3   123123          C               a             NaN
6   123123          D             NaN           23423
1   123124          B             NaN               7
4   123124          C               c             NaN
7   123124          D             NaN            6464
2   123144          B             NaN              99
5   123144          C               x             NaN
8   123144          D             NaN             234
```

Comment: As you requested comments, here are some critics. The code is not very scalable, if there were other types this would become cumbersome. Also it requires a fair amount of hardcoding of the variables. But seems to work nicely for the provided dataset. You'll get my +1 ;)

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate the comments and will work my way up toward writing more elegant codes. And please feel free to critic my code whenever you have time :)

Answer (score 2):

```
df.melt(id_vars='FIELD_A', var_name='FIELD_NAME', value_name='FIELD_VALUE').sort_values(by='FIELD_A').reset_index(drop=True)
```

outputs

```
    FIELD_A FIELD_NAME  FIELD_VALUE
0   123123  FIELD_B     8
1   123123  FIELD_C     a
2   123123  FIELD_D     23423
3   123124  FIELD_B     7
4   123124  FIELD_C     c
5   123124  FIELD_D     6464
6   123144  FIELD_B     99
7   123144  FIELD_C     x
8   123144  FIELD_D     234
```

I hope this helps to achieve your desired output!

We can stretch it further:

```py
(df
.melt(
    id_vars='FIELD_A', 
    var_name='FIELD_NAME', 
    value_name='FIELD_VALUE')
.assign(
    FIELD_NAME = lambda df: df.FIELD_NAME.str[-1], 
    FIELD_NUM_VALUE = lambda df: df.FIELD_VALUE.where(df.FIELD_VALUE.map(type) == int),
     FIELD_STR_VALUE = lambda df: np.where(df.FIELD_NUM_VALUE.isna(), df.FIELD_VALUE, np.nan))
    .drop(columns='FIELD_VALUE')
    .sort_values(by='FIELD_A', ignore_index = True)
)

   FIELD_A FIELD_NAME FIELD_NUM_VALUE FIELD_STR_VALUE
0   123123          B               8             NaN
1   123123          C             NaN               a
2   123123          D           23423             NaN
3   123124          B               7             NaN
4   123124          C             NaN               c
5   123124          D            6464             NaN
6   123144          B              99             NaN
7   123144          C             NaN               x
8   123144          D             234             NaN
```

Another option, with `pd.Series.str.extract`:

```py
temp = df.melt(id_vars='FIELD_A', var_name='FIELD_NAME', value_name='FIELD_VALUE')
temp = temp.assign(FIELD_NAME = lambda df: df.FIELD_NAME.str[-1])
regex = r"(?P<FIELD_STR_VALUE>\D+)|(?P<FIELD_NUM_VALUE>\d+)"
extract = temp.FIELD_VALUE.astype(str).str.extract(regex)
temp.drop(columns='FIELD_VALUE').assign(**extract)

   FIELD_A FIELD_NAME FIELD_STR_VALUE FIELD_NUM_VALUE
0   123123          B             NaN               8
1   123124          B             NaN               7
2   123144          B             NaN              99
3   123123          C               a             NaN
4   123124          C               c             NaN
5   123144          C               x             NaN
6   123123          D             NaN           23423
7   123124          D             NaN            6464
8   123144          D             NaN             234
```